# Remembering Authentication

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, authentication

I have a flutter mobile app that uses firebase authentication to authenticate users with email/phone and some third party providers. How can I make it so that when the app is uninstalled & reinstalled, the credentials are already saved, similar to how instagram or facebook saves your login information when you reinstall the app?

From my understanding so far, at least for iOS, this happens when your credentials are saved in the keychain. Based on that, I found this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage which I think would allow me to save the credentials and then when the user reinstalls the app, I would be able to check if those credentials exist and then log the user in.

Am I understanding this correctly? Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Flutter Secure Storage is similar to `NSUserDefaults` in iOS.

If you want to check whether app is running for the first time after re-install, `shared_preferences` can be used along with FSS.